# Recompile an apk after making some changes to androidmanifest?

Tags: expo, apktool, targetsdkversion

So I generated an apk using react native expo, and coud not find a way to set target sdk version, so the solution suggested in forums is detaching my app, and this is impossible for our app, it will be ruined, I know that !

So, I am thinking of using apktool to just set the targetVersion! I got a folder from my apk using this command :

```
apktool d myapk.apk
```

I made changes in androidmanifest.xml, and ..

I want to get my apk again from this compiled apk. from their documentation, I don't see how they do this! They use the commend with `b` option, but not on folders !!

Any idea or help woulb be much appreciaed.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `apktool d myapk.apk` you will get folder `myapk/` which has your entire decompiled apk.

After changing what you need (in this case you actually need to change the `targetSdkVersion` parameter in *apktool.yml*, not in *AndroidManifest.xml*), you need to run `apktool b myapk/` (passing that *myapk* folder), so you will get the recompiled apk in *myapk/dist/myapk.apk*.

```yaml
sdkInfo:
  targetSdkVersion: '27' #(or any new desired target version)
```

After that you still need to sign and zipalign that apk to make it work on your device.